# Packages providing debug symbols for xserver-xorg

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, kubuntu, xorg

I'm trying to debug a crash of the xorg server in Kubuntu 20.04, so I'd need the symbols to get a decent backtrace. I therefore read this page: https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/ServerDebugging/. It says I should install xserver-xorg-core-dbg and another package specific of my GPU, which in my case is nVidia with proprietary drivers.

I suspect the last one does not exist, maybe it is included in the closed source drivers, is this correct? But what about the first one? I cannot find it for 20.04. Isn't there any package providing the symbols?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually rebuilding the package with debug symbols. Couldn't find the proper package in the repos.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working for bionic by installing the debug symbols keyring:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

Then I added this line at the end of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

For 20.04 the line would be:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal main restricted universe multiverse
```

If you have the `-updates` repository enabled then a line like this would also be needed:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

This ensures that the debug package version matches the version of the main package. Otherwise you may see an error like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core-dbgsym : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (= 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that I ran `apt-get update` and was then able to run:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-core-dbgsym
```

To see a list of all X server debug symbol packages you can use:

```
apt-cache search 'xserver-xorg.*dbgsym'
```

I based this on information I found in this Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-cache` to find:

```
$ apt-cache search xserver-xorg|grep dev
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev - X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
xserver-xorg-dev - Xorg X server - development files
```

The package you want is `xserver-xorg-dev`

Comment: I though dev packages included libs and headers. Do they also contain libs with symbols?

Comment: The packages contain all the binaries, libraries, scripts, etc to allow a user to use the package.  The `-dev` packages contain additional files useful to developers of that package.

Comment: Installing that is not presenting symbols in gdb. I had to build the package by myself in debug.